# Have an equivalent to pandas.merge with huge dataframes and no additional libraries

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I am currently dealing with very big dataframes of a few millions rows each.

However, my computer is often not powerful enough to perform the merge on both dataframes with pandas.merge

I would like to find another way of doing it, more memory efficient, and ideally without using needing new libraries. The objective is to extract the rows that are not in both dataframes, with a flag to know in which dataframe it is present.

The two key aspects is that I need to keep the flag, but also that sometimes a row is in both dataframes but not at the same index, so this issue needs to be covered.

In the very most cases, the columns will be the same between the two dataframes.

Thank you very much

I have already tried converting the dataframes into dictionaries but was not successful.

I am aware of the disk library, sadly, I would like not to have to use another library.

I also thought of parallelization, but as a beginner I am not really sure how to use it.

Thank you guys.

Comment: please give explicit reproducible (minimal) examples of your datasets, the expected output and the commands that you are currently using.

Comment: Hello, sorry this is my first post.


The input would be two dataframes, with more than 1 000 000 rows and about 10-20 columns. The two dataframes have the same name and amount of columns. 

The expected output is a dataframe that includes all the rows that are present in one of the two dataframes but not the other. 
The output must have the same columns as the previous two, with an additional "Flag" column to indicate whether the row was only in the 1st DF, or only in the 2nd.

Comment: INPUT:
    Fruit  Quantity  Price
0   Apple    10    0.5
1  Banana   15    0.2
2  Orange   8    0.3
3   Mango  12    0.8
4  Grapes  20    0.6

Fruit  Quantity  Price
0      Apple        10    0.5
1  Pineapple     1    8.0
2     Orange         8    0.3
3      Mango        12    0.8


OUPUT : Fruit  Quantity  Price      _merge
0      Apple        10    0.5        both
1  Pineapple         1    8.0   left_only
2     Orange         8    0.3        both
3      Mango        12    0.8        both
4     Banana        15    0.2  right_only
5     Grapes        20    0.6  right_only`

Comment: please [edit] the question with a DataFrame constructor of your inputs (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/16343464) for more details on how to provide a minimal example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: When you're encountering limitations with a library, don't be afraid to look for a different library that can better handle your solution. Why not try polars?

Answer (score 0):

This approach iterates through each row in df1 and determines if the row exists in df2. If not, the row is stored in a new df called "unique_to_df1". The same is then applied to df2 comparing to df1. I add a "Source" column to each to show which dataframe the row came from originally and then concatenate the two.

This approach will be slow but should (I think) circumvent the issues you're currently having. I'm not 100% sure because I don't have millions of rows to test on. It may serve as a band-aid solution until someone else comes up with a better approach. Let me know how it goes!

```
import pandas as pd

# Load up nonsense sample data (I made this up)
data1 = {'Quantity': [1, 2, 3, 4],
         'Fruit': ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'date'],
        'Price':[0.4,0.2,0.3,0.2]}
data2 = {'Quantity': [3, 1, 5, 6],
         'Fruit': ['cherry', 'apple', 'elderberry', 'fig'],
        'Price':[0.4,0.4,0.3,0.2]}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

# Initialize an empty dataframes to store unique rows from df1 and df2
unique_to_df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Quantity', 'Fruit', 'Price'])
unique_to_df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Quantity', 'Fruit', 'Price'])

#Iterate through df1 to find unique rows (not in df2)
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if not (df2 == row).all(axis=1).any():
        unique_to_df1.loc[len(unique_to_df1)] = row

#Iterate through df1 to find unique rows (not in df2)
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    if not (df1 == row).all(axis=1).any():
        unique_to_df2.loc[len(unique_to_df2)] = row

#Add new column with Source dataframe
unique_to_df1['Source'] = 'df1'
unique_to_df2['Source'] = 'df2'

#Concatenate the two dataframes
final_df = pd.concat([unique_to_df1, unique_to_df2])
```